# Pass from UIUserNotificationTypeNone to UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Do you know a way to pass from UIUserNotificationTypeNone to UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound (iOS8)?

To pass to UIUserNotificationTypeNone works well but not when the user try to switch again to enable ...

This is my code:

```
 // Register for Push Notifications, if running iOS 8
                    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
                    {
                        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
                        UIUserNotificationSettings * settingsAvailable = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
                        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settingsAvailable];
                        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
                        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
                    }
```

After switch to enable the method of delegate "didRegisterUserNotificationSettings"

```
// Register to receive notifications
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];

NSLog(@"The app is registered for the types: %@", notificationSettings);
```

returns:

```
The app is registered for the types: <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x15e9e790; types: (none);>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

That's because the notification setting has been turned off in the system setting.

Comment: As described in the docs for application:didRegisterUserNOtificationSettings:, "Your app’s request is combined with the user’s current preferences to determine what notification types are allowed and the results are delivered to this method in the notificationSettings parameter."